# UiPath automation Assistance

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I am getting below error while running automation via UIPath Assistance,

> CacheMetadata for activity 'Main' threw 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException: Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities}Variable({clr-namespace:Microsoft.Identity.Client;assembly=Microsoft.Identity.Client}IPublicClientApplication)'. at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartObject(XamlType xamlType) at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader) at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter) at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.FuncFactory`1.Evaluate() at System.Activities.DynamicActivity.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings) at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors) at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback) at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors) at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors) at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.RequiresCompilation(IDynamicActivity dynamicActivity, LocationReferenceEnvironment environment, String& language)'. at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.RequiresCompilation(IDynamicActivity dynamicActivity, LocationReferenceEnvironment environment, String& language) at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.Compile(IDynamicActivity dynamicActivity, LocationReferenceEnvironment environment) at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, ActivityXamlServicesSettings settings) at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.Load(XmlReader xmlReader, ActivityXamlServicesSettings settings) at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.Load(Stream stream, ActivityXamlServicesSettings settings) at UiPath.Executor.WorkflowRuntime.Load(String workflowFile) at UiPath.Executor.RobotRunner.InitWorkflowApplication() at UiPath.Executor.RobotRunner.d__84.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by doing below Steps .

**Go to :**
**C:\User\{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet**  and if you find **NuGet.Config** file then Delete it .

1. Now go to UIPath Studio and Click start.
2. Click Process and you will get **New Blank Process**.
3. Please select Language and click **create** and You will get **Design Page**. Click **Manage Package** and go to All Packages.
4. Now search for **UIPath.Web.Activities** and choose install and Click Save .

Restart UIPath and it should work.